# Doesn't methyl amine give carbylamine test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

> A compound $\ce X$ of formula $\ce{C2H5NO2}$ on treatment with $\ce {HNO2}$ 
>    $(\ce{NaNO2}+\ce{HCl})$ gives off an inactive gas $\ce Y$ and forms $\ce Z$. When heated with soda lime, $\ce X$ gives $\ce{A(CH5N)}$ soluble in acid. Find the true statements :
>
> 1. $\ce A$ answers carbylamine test.
> 2. $\ce X$ is an amino acid.
> 3. $\ce Y$ is $\ce{CO2}$.
> 4. $\ce Z$ is a hydroxyl acid.

**My attempt :**

$\ce X$ is glycine.

$\ce A$ is methyl amine.

$\ce Y$ is dinitrogen.

$\ce Z$ is 2-hydroxy ethanoic acid.

Hence, correct options should be : $1,2,4$. But the answer given is $2,4$.

Can anyone help me to understand if and where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed correct.

$\ce{HOOC-CH2-NH2(X) ->[HNO2] HOOC-CH2-OH (Z) + N2(Y)}$

$\ce{HOOC-CH2-NH2(X) ->[soda lime] CH2-NH2(A)}$

Also, $ \ce{(A) + CHCl3 + 3KOH ->[Heat] CH3-NC + 3KCl + 3H2O}$.

Methylamine [does give the carbylamine test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbylamine_reaction).

So clearly, the answer given must be wrong.

The correct options are 1,2 and 4.